# Pass value to next function

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried to load data using two functions, and then use the data for "plot" and "analyze". however, when I run the "plot" or "analyze", the program tries to load the data again. What's wrong with my coding?
Or, are there better ways to achieve my goals?

My goals are to load data from computer,  plot them, and then do similarity measures between the two data.

Thank you very much.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

#load database
def load_database():
    sample_rate = 200001
    nsamples = 40000
    t = arange(nsamples) / sample_rate
    data1 = np.loadtxt(filedialog.askopenfilename(), delimiter=';')
    x1 = data1[:, 0] / 100000
    y1 = data1[:, 1]
    nyq_rate = sample_rate /100
    width = 50 / nyq_rate
    ripple_db = 100
    N, beta = kaiserord(ripple_db, width)
    cutoff_hz = 0.0002
    taps = firwin(N, cutoff_hz / nyq_rate, window=('kaiser', beta))
    filtered_y1 = lfilter(taps, 1.0, y1)
    x_1 = x1[::400]  # sampling every 400 points
    y_1 = filtered_y1[::400]  # sampling every 400 points
    return x_1, y_1

def load_data_for_analyze():
    sample_rate = 200001
    nsamples = 40000
    t = arange(nsamples) / sample_rate
    data2 = np.loadtxt(filedialog.askopenfilename(), delimiter=';')
    x2 = data2[:, 0] / 100000
    y2 = data2[:, 1]
    nyq_rate = sample_rate /100
    width = 50 / nyq_rate
    ripple_db = 100
    N, beta = kaiserord(ripple_db, width)
    cutoff_hz = 0.0002
    taps = firwin(N, cutoff_hz / nyq_rate, window=('kaiser', beta))
    filtered_y2 = lfilter(taps, 1.0, y2)
    x_2 = x2[::400]  # sampling every 400 points
    y_2 = filtered_y2[::400]  # sampling every 400 points
    return x_2, y_2

def analyze():
    x_1, y_1 = load_database()
    x_2, y_2 = load_data_for_analyze()
    A = np.array([x_1, y_1]).T
    B = np.array([x_2, y_2]).T
    dh_1, ind1, ind2 = directed_hausdorff(A, B)
    df_1 = similaritymeasures.frechet_dist(A, B)
    dtw_1, d = similaritymeasures.dtw(A, B)
    pcm_1 = similaritymeasures.pcm(A, B)
    area_1 = similaritymeasures.area_between_two_curves(A, B)
    cl_1 = similaritymeasures.curve_length_measure(A, B)

    print('dh_1 =', dh_1, '\n\n', 'df_1 =',df_1, '\n\n' 'dtw_1 =',dtw_1, '\n\n', 'pcm_1 =',pcm_1, '\n\n',
          'cl1_1 =', cl_1, '\n\n', 'area_1 =', area_1)
    # print('dh_2 =',dh_2,' ', 'df_2 = ', df_2, 'dtw_2 =', ' ',dtw_2, 'pcm_2 =', ' ', pcm_2,'cl1_2 =', ' ',cl_2, 'area_2 =', ' ',area_2)
    # print('PCM_1 =', ' ',pcm_1)
    user_inp = simpledialog.askstring(title=' ', prompt='Selections from the database')

    if pcm_1 < 80:

        print('The letter you wrote is:', user_inp)
    else:
        print('The letter you wrote is: B')

def plot():
    x_1, y_1 = load_database()
    x_2, y_2 = load_data_for_analyze()
    plt.plot(x_1, y_1)
    plt.plot(x_2, y_2)
    plt.show()

root.title('Universal input analyser')

button1 = Button(root, text='Load from database', font='Arial 20 bold', bg='blue', width=25, command=load_database)
button2 = Button(root, text='Plot', font='Arial 20 bold', bg='blue', width=25, command=plot)
button3 = Button(root, text='Load data for analyze', font='Arial 20 bold', bg='blue', width=25, command=load_data_for_analyze)
button4 = Button(root, text='Analyze', font='Arial 20 bold', bg='blue', width=25, command=analyze)

button1.pack(pady=20, padx=200)
button2.pack(pady=20, padx=200)
button4.pack(pady=20, padx=200)
button3.pack(pady=20, padx=200)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainloop()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: don't use plot() as a function name. There is already a function for it

Comment: *"however, when I run the "plot" or "analyze", the program tries to load the data again."* - both `plot` and `analyze` call `load_database` and `load_data_for_analyze`.  Why do you expect them to not try to load the data?

Comment: `plot` and `analyze` both call `load_database()` so the database is being reloaded each time. You should make `x_1, y_1` and `x_2, y_2` global variables and set them once.

Comment: Thank you Mike67, that helps indeed.

Comment: Another question regarding the same code. The "plot" and the "analyze" could not be performed at the same time using the buttons. I must kill one before I can run the other. How to solve that problem? Thank you.